# SWT Label background color in Group [MacOSX]

Tags: java, macos, widget, swt, eclipse-kepler

[image]

The `Label` background color looks terrible on Mac, when it's placed in a `Group`.

From what I've read, this has been fixed already, a long time ago.

- [Bug #1](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=47146)
- [Bug #2](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=290212)
- [Bug #3](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=297633)
- [Bug #4](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=327790)

If these are marked as fixed, then why aren't the changes present in Kepler 4.3.1?

I don't want to open ANOTHER bug on Eclipse's Bugzilla. Also, I don't want to implement workarounds in our system.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of SWT are you using? One of the bug reports states that it was updated in 3.7. If you're developing a plugin, just ignore my comment.

Comment: @Baz I'm developing a plugin (several actually), so I'm ignoring your comment! :-)

Comment: Normally the whole group is the slightly darker shade of gray

Comment: for some reason, I still get this. Using eclipse.swt 4.3. Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @mateuscb No, not really. I have to manually set a background.